# How do I write a callback function that returns an array of pointers?

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to implement a Callback function that would return an Array of pointers. Here is my code, but I keep getting an error message. Does anyone know the correct syntax for a callback function that returns an array of pointers?

code:

```
    //The original array is here:
    __declspec(dllexport) bot_movestate_t *botmovestates[MAX_CLIENTS+1];
    __declspec(dllexport) struct bot_movestate_s **Getbotmovestates( void )
    {
        return botmovestates;
    }
```

/---------------/

```
//The caller    
    struct bot_movestate_s *ai_main_botmovestates[MAX_CLIENTS+1];
    typedef struct bot_movestate_s **(* fGetbotmovestates_t)( void );
    struct bot_movestate_s **fGetbotmovestates( fGetbotmovestates_t pfGetbotmovestates ){
        return pfGetbotmovestates();
    }

    //sm func
    void smfunc()
    {
        fGetbotmovestates_t pfGetbotmovestates;
        HMODULE hLib;

    /////////////////////////////

        hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("smdll.dll"));
            if (hLib == NULL) {
            //Module not found, permission denied, ...
            return; //inform caller of error
        }

        pfGetbotmovestates = (fGetbotmovestates_t)GetProcAddress(hLib, TEXT("Getbotmovestates"));
        if ( pfGetbotmovestates == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        ai_main_botmovestates = fGetbotmovestates(pfGetbotmovestates);//error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value

    /////////////////////////////

    }
    //error
    error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
```

Comment: Either return a _pointer to a pointer_ or use a container like the `g_list` (from GLib) instead of an array and return a pointer to that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't return arrays.

Instead, make the caller pass an array, which you fill in.

If you allocate and return an array, you end up with problems of mismatched deallocator, when the caller goes to free it.

Another option is to use a `SAFEARRAY`, where the allocator and deallocator are both provided by the OS, not your compiler vendor.

Comment: The code that allocates/dellocates the array is written already in the original code. I just would like to have access to that array from the outside. Do you know what syntax above is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `ai_main_botmovestates` as an array of pointers, but you're trying to assign it a single value. Either you need to declare it as a pointer to a pointer, or you need to assign a single element of the array.

Comment: I redefined it to be like this, but now I am only getting the pointer to the first cell in the array, and not the whole array. Anyone has any ideas on the write syntax? struct bot_movestate_s **ai_main_botmovestates;
typedef struct bot_movestate_s **(* fGetbotmovestates_t)( void );

Answer (score 0):

I changed the definition to:

```
struct bot_movestate_s **ai_main_botmovestates;
```